# Gitignore: add a file that is in an excluded folder

Tags: git

Currently I have the following in my `.gitignore`:

```
...
sites/default/files/*
!sites/default/files/Library/bannerpt2.jpg
...
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is I don't want any of `sites/default/files/` EXCEPT for `sites/default/files/Library/bannerpt2.jpg`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to manually include all subdirectories in the path, unfortunately. This should work:

```
...
sites/default/files/*
!sites/default/files/Library/

sites/default/files/Library/*
!sites/default/files/Library/bannerpt2.jpg
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the file in the excluded folder using `git add -f file`

Sample Interaction:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/killerx/temp/.git/
$ echo "*" > .gitignore
$ touch a.txt
$ git add a.txt
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
a.txt
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
$ git add -f a.txt
$ git commit -m "t"
[master (root-commit) db22f19] t
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
$ echo "a" > a.txt
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   a.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: But this is just a 'one time' addition no? Its not added to the repo permanently?

Comment: Of course it is permanent, as shown if you do a change after the commit it shows up in the change list.